# Xcode error: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key *

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIView 0x104908040> `setValue:forUndefinedKey:`]: this class is not **key value coding-compliant** for the key signinbutton.'
```

I'm getting an error after building and launching my iOS app. I see that other people have got this error before, but after trying all the solutions, none of them have worked for me. It's not a naming issue, or a bad connection, as far as I can tell. I've deleted the app, restarted, etc. I've tried with different outlets. This is how it goes: my app works perfectly, then I add any sort of `@IBOutlet` to my `ViewController`, all looks good. Build and run, and the app loads to a blank screen and I get that error in my console.

I've been trying every solution on stackoverflow for the past 6 hours. None of them work.

This is my `ViewController`.

```
import UIKit

class UIView: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var signInButton: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}
```

My `AppDelegate` file is just as it comes default.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
```

and so on...

Why isn't this working?

**EDIT: Changing the class to  `class HomeViewController: UIViewController` does nothing.**

Note: This is ***not*** a duplicate question. No solution posted on Stack Overflow has worked so far for me.

Comment: change your classname from `UIView` to something else that is not a part of ios default keywords

Comment: In the formulation of your edit, you say _not a duplicate question_ and _no solution posted [...] has worked_, which is a bit contradictory: how can there be solutions posted already if there wasn't this question before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the name of your controller to some name.

```
class UIView: UIViewController // This is wrong
```

`class HomeViewController: UIViewController` : This is right

Also update the class of controller in `storyboard`: Select controller in storyboard. Change `file's owner`.

Comment: How do I update the class of the controller in the storyboard?

Comment: Select controller in storyboard. Change `file's owner`

Comment: @pkv456 mention above in his answer to change class name and also set that name in storyboard.

Comment: @pkc456 Do you mean "View Controller"? Using Xcode version 9.2 I don't see any option to change the file's owner. Also, what do I change it to?

Comment: 1) Open storyboard. 2) Click on controller where you declared `signInButton` 3) On the left panel, you will see File's owner. Click on it. 4) On the right panel, there is option to change the class of controller

Comment: @esalberg - “File owner” is used in NIBs. It’s the “base class” in a storyboard scene. Are you using NIB or storyboard?

Comment: @Rob I don't think I"m using NIBs. I've found where the "File owner" _should_ be (In the Document Outline) but there's nothing there. Just the Home View Controller Scene, and it's children. What do I do know that I know I have **no** File owner?

Comment: @esalberg - When you select the UI in the project navigator panel in the left, does it have an extension `.xib` or `.storyboard`? If a storyboard, you are _not_ going to look for the “file owner”. It’s called that for NIBs, but not storyboards. I’m presuming you’re dealing with storyboard. So, select the view controller in the “document outline” of your storyboard, go to the “identity inspector” in the panel on the right, and check out the “Custom Class” section and supply your new view controller class name as the “class” for that storyboard scene.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly create the outlet of signinbutton in your view controller[To Learn more about outlets and Actions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-ZaRC8L6uE)

Comment: I've done that already...

Answer (score 0):

Simple, if your class is a **UIView**, either subclass **UIView** or your custom UIView subclass.

If your class is a **UIViewController**, either subclass **UIViewController** or your custom UIViewController subclass.

```
UIView: UIViewController doesnt make sense to the compiler.
```

I would like to mention some background info:

x : y means,
x is a subclass of y, since you mention it is your **ViewController** file, so in order for your code to compile, you can simply change the name of your class from UIView to a custom name

Also UIViewController is another Class in UIKit, just like UIView or UITableView, but not the controller of the child class. 
Meanning when x : y, y is not the controller of x, but indeed x is the controller, and x is subclassed from Y

Comment: You are right but It it very good If you tell your opinion in comment area.

Comment: What would be the best way to go about it? `UIView: UIViewController` is how it is by default.

Comment: @esalberg i have edited my answer, hope it helps

Comment: So, in theory, changing it to `class HomeViewController: UIViewController` should work, yes? But it does not.

Comment: @easlberg check your storyboard setting whether the customer class in inspector panel has set to HomeViewController, if error still exists i suppose its another error, just update the post

Answer (score 0):

Don't use **UIView** as the class name, because there's a **system** of UIView classes.